# Pipe microphone to speakers with no delay

Tags: audio, microphone

I want to plug a microphone into my computer and pipe the sound out to speakers, and I want to have as little delay as possible.  And I would prefer to use command line to do this.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

(I'm thinking of putting this in my van, so we can use it like a PA system. Our van has a 1/8 inch audio jack line in.  Actually, it's so that my wife can read a book to our kids without having to yell.)

Edit: About my system:  I'll use whatever software I need to.  For hardware, I was hoping to use a Raspberry Pi, but I would consider a laptop if I have to.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about your system? Also, are you using alsa, pulse, jack,...?

Comment: This will likely give you a feedback loop and it's a little difficult to filter this out. (With a very low delay a low-pass filter will help.)

Comment: I was thinking that using a microphone close to the mouth would minimize the feedback.

Comment: use analog hardware for no delay - get a microphone preamplifier that can run off batteries or the car 12v supply so microphone can be connected direct to line in